# Gradient calculation with backpropagation through $max$ function

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

Suppose I have a neural network with several layers and on one layer I have "bad" activation function with respect to its differential properties. This function is a $max$, e.g.:
$$
f(x) = max(g(x), h(x))
$$
for some $g$ and $h$.

I heard that there are some algorithms that allow us to use backpropagation even in this case, but unfortunately I can't find any of them. I looked in several books:

- Neural Networks: A Comprehensive Foundation by Haykin
- Deep Learning (Adaptive Computation and Machine Learning series) by Goodfellow et al.

But these books doesn't mention this topic at all.

Moreover, I heard that these methods somehow use Gumbel distribution (but I'm not sure if it is true). That's all information I have for now.

Where can I read about these algorithms of computing gradient in such cases? Unfortunately Google didn't help me with this task.

Comment: subgradients ??

Comment: @seanv507 it seems to be the thing I'm looking for, but are there other methods that provide such functionality?

Answer (score 2):

$$
f' (x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
  g' (x) & g (x) > h (x)\\
  h' (x) & h (x) > g (x)\\
  \text{Undefined} & g (x) = h (x), g' (x) \neq h' (x)
\end{array}\right.
$$

Automatic differentiation packages should be able to handle this just fine, except for the problematic $g(x)=h(x)$ case which can have issues.